# "incorrect checksum for freed object", but I didn't free it

Tags: c++

**Problem solved**

Thanks all for your engagement in my error searching!

Thanks @Basile Starynkevitch for telling me about valgrind. Thanks @Anders K. for pointing out that it might have to do with the allocation/deallocation of x and w.

The problem was that the allocated memory for double x[] was too small, which lead to, which Anders pointed out, that I overwrote data in other places. This eventually lead to the crashes of my program.

Hans

..........................................................................................................................................

Sitting with my master thesis trying to implement a self organizing map (SOM) when I encountered the following error:

```
program(39652,0x7fff70055cc0) malloc: *** error for object 0x100555108:  
incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
```

The thing is that I haven't deallocated any memory. The object that is causing the problem is  a `vector<Point> points` object. The Point class has a member `vector<PriceData> data`. `PriceData` is a struct holding primitive values. Here is the stacktrace:

```
#0  0x00007fff803880b6 in __kill ()
#1  0x00007fff804289f6 in abort ()
#2  0x00007fff8041762d in szone_error ()
#3  0x00007fff8033e80b in tiny_malloc_from_free_list ()
#4  0x00007fff8033dabd in szone_malloc_should_clear ()
#5  0x00007fff8033d98a in malloc_zone_malloc ()
#6  0x00007fff8033bc88 in malloc ()
#7  0x00007fff88732f05 in operator new ()
#8  0x000000010001d3d1 in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<PriceData>::allocate () at stl_construct.h:182
#9  0x000000010001d3f9 in std::_Vector_base<PriceData, std::allocator<PriceData> >::_M_allocate () at stl_construct.h:182
#10 0x000000010001d794 in std::_Vector_base<PriceData, std::allocator<PriceData> >::_Vector_base () at stl_construct.h:182
#11 0x000000010001d82f in std::vector<PriceData, std::allocator<PriceData> >::vector () at stl_construct.h:182
#12 0x000000010001d8c3 in Point::Point () at stl_construct.h:182
#13 0x000000010002193e in Som::startTraining () at stl_construct.h:182
#14 0x0000000100017465 in main () at main_controller.cpp:42
```

It goes wrong when I am trying to train my network. I pass a reference to the `points` object, which will not go out of scope here, right?

main_controller:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stock_data_controller.h"
#include "pattern_controller.h"
#include "point.h"
#include "som.h"
#include <ctime>


using namespace std;

int main() {

    PatternController pc()

    // Train Kohonen network
    Som som(pc.points);
    som.startTraining(20000); // goes wrong in here!


    return 0;
}
```

Training works for approx 100 to 500 times (different every time) then I get the error. I have marked the place in the code wherefrom the error is thrown. Something has at this point gone bad with the `points` object.

Here is the data for som.cpp:

```
#include "som.h"
#include <cmath>
#include <cassert>

Som::Som(vector<Point> &pts, int gsize)  { //: points(pts) {

    // Initiera variabler
    points = pts;
    nrPoints = points.size();
    ptSize = points.at(1).data.size();
    gridSize = gsize;
    dimensions = 4*ptSize;

    initW();
    initX();
};

Som::~Som() {
    for (int i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < gridSize; j++) {
            delete [] w[i][j];
        }
        delete [] w[i];
    }
    delete [] w;
};

void Som::startTraining(int nrIterations) {

    for(int i=0; i<nrIterations; i++) {
        // choose random pt

        // EROOR IS HERE // 
        Point pt = points.at(randomPointIndex()); // I have tried with constant 20 and got the same error.. 
            // ERROR IS HERE //


        buildX(pt);

        // Find winning neuron

        findWinningNeuron();

        // update weights
        cout << "Update weights" << endl;
        updateWeights(i);
        cout << "fUpdate weights" << endl;

        cout << "Iteration: " << i << endl;
    }

    cout << "Training of SOM is complete." << endl;
};

void Som::findWinningNeuron() {
    //init
    winner.distance = 1e6;

    for (int i=0; i<gridSize; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<gridSize; j++) {
            double dist = computeEDistance(w[i][j]);
            if (dist<winner.distance) {
                winner.distance = dist;
                winner.row = i;
                winner.column = j;
            }
        }
    }
    assert( winner.distance != 1e6 );
};



void Som::updateWeights(int iterNr) {
    for (int i=0; i<gridSize; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<gridSize; j++) {
            double eta = computeEta(iterNr);
            double h = computeH(iterNr, i, j);
            for (int k=0; k<dimensions; k++) {
                w[i][j][k] = w[i][j][k] + eta*h*(x[k]-w[i][j][k]);
            }
        }
    }
};

void Som::initW() {
    cout << "initW" << endl;
    srand(time(NULL));

    // Creating w
    cout << "creating w"<< endl;
    w = new double**[gridSize];
    for (int i = 0; i<gridSize; i++) {
        w[i] = new double*[gridSize];
        for (int j=0; j<gridSize; j++) {
            w[i][j] = new double[dimensions];
        }
    }
    // cout << "w size: " << sizeof( w[0][0] ) / sizeof( w[0][0][0] ) << endl;
    // Populating w
    cout << "populatiing w" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i<gridSize; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<gridSize; j++) {
            for (int k=0; k<dimensions; k++) {
                double r = double(rand()) / RAND_MAX * 0.4 +0.8;
                w[i][j][k] = r;
                            }
            }
        }       
    }

};

void Som::initX() {
    x= new double[ptSize];
};

void Som::buildX(Point &pt) {
    for (int i=0; i<ptSize; i++) {
        x[i*4] = pt.data.at(i).open;
        x[i*4+1] = pt.data.at(i).high;
        x[i*4+2] = pt.data.at(i).low;
        x[i*4+3] = pt.data.at(i).close;
    }
};

int Som::randomPointIndex() {
    // random point
    int r = rand() % nrPoints;
    cout << "r: " << r << endl;
    return r;
};
```

som.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "point.h"
#include "models.h"

class Som {
private:
public:
    // Members
    double ***w;
    double *x;
    vector<Point> points;
    ...
    winner_t winner;

}
```

Grateful for any help or pointers!!
Thanks,
Hans

Comment: 1) Never say `using namespace` in a header file; 2) if you find yourself saying `***`, step back and rethink.

Comment: In general, people are more motivated to answer if you strip al this code and try to find the minimum of code that will still produce the problem. The code provided is much too much. Take advantage of this note. Good luck!

Comment: Sometimes unrelated frees could cause errors in other parts of programs. I think you should take a closer look on 'w' and 'x' which you allocate and delete.

Comment: Adding to what @bert-jan says, the code you provide is also too little. It is in short mostly irrelevant code. The code most likely pertaining to the problem is not here.

Comment: `new[]` and `delete[]`? Go away and change it, and come back.

Comment: Ok. I'll strip the code. Sorry for that.. @DeadMG: What do you mean with your comment? Could you please specify?

Comment: @KerrekSB : Thanks for the tip. I took a step back and with googles help I realized why it is not a good idea using namespace.

Comment: Use C++11 containers like  `std::vector`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using a tool like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: Valgrind will show you the line in your code that is causing the improper free. You should take this as a opportunity to include it in your workflow.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of this tool. It seems awesome! I have downloaded it and are about to try it out.

Comment: I couldn't find anything using the memcheck. However, I did find the error, please see below. If SGcheck would have worked on OSX valgrind would probably have found it.. valgrind is brutal to your program though.. :)